# How to search through custom component files and reference mysql tables for Joomla's front-end com_search component?

Tags: search, joomla, components, customization

I'm using Joomla 1.5 and I'm trying to get the search component in the front-end to reference my custom components, not those just through com_content and com_newsfeeds, etc.  A lot of my custom components get data from MySQL so it would help even more if I were able to add the tables for com_search to go through as well (in addition to referencing the actual file for the component itself, where the static HTML surrounding the PHP tags are written).  Has anybody tried doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to create search plugin, which will do search through your own component. Check this:

http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_search_plugin

Also, would be helpfull to look on default joomla search plugins. They are stored there

`\plugins\search\`

I hope it will be helpfull.